# Jenkins Keeps Showing Error as "MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist." while trying to build a .NET core application using Jenkins

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jenkins, msbuild, devops

I am trying to build the ASP.NET core project using Jenkins. I am using the Execute shell command option in the Build Step.

But I am getting error like this:

I have also tried using the MsBuild Plugin, and I am getting this error. I don't know how to find the MsBuild install path on Linux.

I am using Gitlab Webhook for source code management. Kindly help.

Comment: Build the project using `dotnet publish <...other args>` command (see the docs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dotnet build`.
To install on linux follow the method : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install